# ASP.Net Core 2 - IIS 502.5 Error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, iis-express, coreclr

I am creating an ASP .Net Core (2.0) MVC application within Visual Studio 2017 which was working absolutely fine.

After turning off my computer yesterday and coming back to my application today, I now receive this browser error when I start the application in chrome without debugging.

Running dotnet run within the directory of the application, I can access the site just fine. It is just when I run it via Visual Studio/IIS Express I get this error.

**HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure**

The application builds and compiles just fine. I have also cleaned the solution.

Looking in the event logs I find:

- Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MYAPP' with
  physical root 'C:\Users\Ben Hawkins\Desktop\Development Folder
  \Dev\Website\Version_2\MYAPP\MYAPP\'
  failed to start process with commandline 'C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Microsoft Visual
  Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web
  Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe -argFile "C:\Users\Ben
  Hawkins\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3547.tmp"', ErrorCode = '**0x80004005** :
  0.

Within my output window in Visual Studio 2017 I recieve this message under
ASP NET CORE WebServer

**Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131534**

**What I have tried:**

1. Cleaning the solution, rebuilding etc
2. Restarting the computer
3. Trying to launch another application. (Same result)
4. Created a new application from scratch. Same result.
5. Repairing Visual Studio Community 2017. Same result.
6. Stopping/Closing IIS Express

My setup was **working perfectly yesterday and suddenly is not.**

Thank you for your time. I hope we can find a solution.

Comment: Have you killed any running iis/iis express processes?

Comment: Using the task bar I right clicked the IIS Express Icon, stopped all applications, then Exited IIS Express. ( Could not find any instance in task manager). Still same result.

Comment: This won't actually solve the problem but should help isolate it as either an iisexpress problem or a .net core problem.  If you open a vs command prompt on the project folder and type "dotnet run" without the quotes what happens?

Comment: Running Dotnet run in the project folder I get the following.. Various info messages, looks to be relating to my models and entity framework info. Nothing seems unusual there... At the end of the info tags I get....Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\Users\Ben Hawkins\Desktop\MYAPP\Dev\Website\Version_2\MYAPP\MYAPP
Now listening on: http://localhost:64702
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. --- However! When I run the application within VS.. It launches http://localhost:64701/ ... Different Port numbers?

Comment: `0x80131534` on .net core is a `COR_E_TYPEINITIALIZATION` error ([per source code here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/f25c4efc8c3fabdf3ae5ff0c02fc66325765b332/src/mscorlib/shared/System/HResults.cs#L107)).  It doesn't have anything to do with time zones.  Just because two different applications return the same integer error code does not mean that the error is the same.  See also [issues in coreclr with that error code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=0x80131534).

Comment: This problem still persists for the second night now. Creating a brand new application still brings up this error. Only when I run dotnet run in cmd can I access the application. I get the errors from Visual Studio and IIS Express

Comment: We have a new Windows 10 installation that is exhibiting the same problem. Have you come across a resolution yet?

Comment: @palehorse I ended up reinstalling windows from scratch I am afraid. It seemed the easiest and quickest option. I've not encountered the problem since. There is just not enough information for this error. Please revisit this thread if you do find a solution. Good Luck!

Comment: Reinstalling Windows is still an answer, which you should post below and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

We finally found the issue! After logging on to the machine as a different user, we saw a warning that the main user had ignored initially. There was a 0 byte file in the root of the directory named "Program" with no file extension. It appears that this causes some sort of issue when VSIISExeLauncher.exe is invoked through Visual Studio. (Note it would work if executed from the command prompt). After deleting the file, everything worked!

We do not know how this file was placed there for certain, but suspect it was some sort of copy error when the user was pulling in files from his old hard drive.

I don't know if anyone else will come across this, but if so hopefully this helps!

Comment: Great! For future reference, where did this warning you speak of appear?

Comment: Further more, the root directory of what? The application? I created new applications and had the problem persist you see.

Comment: The message was a small dialog when logging in to the machine. The directory was the root of the boot drive. "C:\Program" was the file. The message read something like "The file C:\Program may cause problems. Would you like to rename it to C:\Program1?"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need install previous versions of .NET Core, isn't it? I installed here and it works now. I had only .NET Core 2.0 installed and I realized that applications with 1.1 stopped so when running. In Windows' event logs I've had the same error registered.

Comment: That's interesting, I too only had .Net Core 2.0 installed. However, my applications, as far as I am aware had always been and were 2.0 at the time of the errors. Unless they developed some kind of dependency.. As I no longer have this issue, perhaps it will be of use to @palehorse

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the IISExpress to IIS by creating new IIS profile and change the Lunch to IIS.  It resolved my problem. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have hit a very similar issue with ASP.net Core 2.0.  I had copied my VS project to a new one, and I was getting this error message.

After doing some research, I was able to determine that the `nlog.config` file was not copied into the bin > Debug > net461 folder.  Once I did this, I was able to run my application.

I found it by running dotnet run from the command line on my project where the csproj files live.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue yesterday (windows 10). 
Solved it this way:

1. Update Microsoft.AspNetCore to latest (Nuget manager - 2.1.3)
2. Make sure the sdk also updated to latest version. if not, update it manually from Nuget console like this: 
   Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.App -Version 2.1.3
3. Download and install latest ASP.NET Core/.NET Core: Runtime & Hosting Bundle
   from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with version 2.2. Reinstalling .NET Core SDK fixed the problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my project was setup as a website in IIS and the file "bin\IISSupport\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" was missing in the project's directory.

I simply selected "IIS" when debugging the project in Visual Studio 2019 and it generated the missing file. It also generated 2 text files (IISExeLauncherArgs.txt, pidfile.txt) in the IISSupport folder, made changes to my web.config file, and my project ran successfully.

After that I was able to access the local website that was setup in IIS without running it in Visual Studio.